# Creating a simple filter in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that contains a bunch of email and looks something like this:

```
From: tommy@gmail.com 
Date: 10 Nov 2014 09:19:59 +0100 (MET)
To: jonny@jonrocks.com
Subject: Let's go have a beer
Hey Jonny, let's have a drink tonight. See ya, Tommy


From: alice@gmail.com 
Date: 11 Dec 2014 19:16:49 +0100 (MET)
To: martha@hotmail.com
Subject: Meeting 
Dear Martha,
Note that our Monday meeting will take place at 10:00 instead of 13:00.
Best regards,
Alice
```

etc

I am writing a perl script allowing the user to give inputs from the header and returning him a message.
for example, the user might type `from alice subject meeting` and would get the email.

So far I have this code I am not sure how to proceed

```
    open(IN, "<emails.txt") or die "Can't open the file";
    print "Enter the search elements from the header:\n";
    chomp($input=<STDIN>);
    # example input from alice subject meeting

    ($from, $who, $where, $what)=split/ /, $input;


while (<IN>)
{
   if( /$from(.)+$who/i ){
    while (<IN>){
          if(/$where(.)+$what/i){
            while ($line = <IN>){
                print $line;
            }
          }

        }  

   }
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid "Not sure how to proceed" means your question is probably a bit too broad for Stack Overflow. If you've a specific thing you're having problems with, then it can be meaningfully answered.

Comment: @Sobique Thank you for the remark. I was hoping that somebody could find a flaw in the logic and send me the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest your first port of call here, is actually parsing mail headers.

Email has a defined format, that basically says that the first line of an email are headers of the form `Headername: header_value\n`. End of headers is marked by `\n\n`. (e.g. two line feeds) which is how you know you're in the 'body' section.

Your samples don't show this though - are you sure that's what you've got to work with?

Anyway - emails also *end* with a blank line. Unfortunately there's no easy way to differentiate someone typing `From: me` in their email, from it being a header - email is pure plain text.

I would suggest starting with a module to do this for you. [`Email::Simple`](http://search.cpan.org/~rjbs/Email-Simple-2.206/lib/Email/Simple.pm)  looks promising.

Failing that - you can use split per header line, and a delimiter of `:`.

```
my %headers; 
while ( <$input> ) {
    if ( m/\w+\:/ ) { 
        my ( $header, $value ) = split ( /:/ );
        $headers{$header} = $value;
    }
}
```

But if you do this, you can supply an argument like: `From=janet` and have it regular expression match your `From` field.

Comment: Thank  you, Sobrique! I will try the Email::Simple module.